# Crystal Reports in C#

Tags: crystal-reports

Actually i try to make the crystal report of my database table values, so far i reached the primary stage of SQL connection. whenever i choose the new connection it seems to produce some errors like,

**A network-related or instance0specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The serve was not found or was not accessive. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to all allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)**

can anyone pls guide me to generate the crystal report.

Thank you,

Arunkumar M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message you seem want to connect over Named Pipes. Check in SQL Server Configuration Manager if you have enabled *Named Pipes*[image]

Also you can use PortQueryUI [http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24009] to see if your SQL Server is from your location accesible and if it listens on Named Pipes.

Alternatively you could try to connect over TCP/IP port 1433. Also check in SQL COnfiguration Manager if you have TCP/IP enabled and check in PortQueryUI if SQL Servers TCP ports are open.

Comment: I enabled all these categories like sharedmemory,namedpipes,TCP/IP. but it produce the same error.

Comment: Thank you so much Robert Niestroj.. In that configuration manager i it show only for protocols for SQLEXPRESS, there is no MSSQLSERVER.

Comment: This is a sample SQL Server. Do it for SQLEXPRESS in your case. Try things and let us know what you found out. What does PortQueryUI say?

Comment: Thank you so much Robert Niestroj . Now it works perfectly.I made some mistakes in that. now i rectify that mistakes & work perfectly.Your answer more help to me.once again thank you.